# Renaming mp3 files according to its metadata

Tags: python, mp3, file-rename, batch-rename

I am trying to rename all my music file with its title in its metadata.
I am using [Pydroid3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3)

```
import os
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

def rename_mp3_files(location):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(location):
        for m_file in files:
            if m_file.endswith(".mp3"):
                old_filepath = os.path.join(root, m_file)

                new_filename = "{}.mp3".format(old_filepath["title"])
                new_filepath = os.path.join(root, new_filename)

                os.rename(old_filepath, new_filepath)

                print (old_filepath["title"])

location = "/storage/emulated/0/Music"
rename_mp3_files(location)
```

But it gives error

```
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in rename_mp3_files
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong
I'm a noob
Please forgive me if i made a mistake or left out something in the question.

Comment: Your code is assuming that `old_filepath["title"]` will somehow get the `title` tag out of the file. `mutagen` will extract that for you, but you do have to ask it to. Simply importing `EasyID3` will not change `old_filepath` from a string into an object that will extract a tag from a file of that name.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
old_filepath = os.path.join(root, m_file)
```

creates `str` and then you do:

```
print(old_filepath["title"])
```

which fails because `str_variable[n]` is way of extracting n-th character from string - `"title"`-th character does not make sense. Try replacing:

```
print(old_filepath["title"])
```

using:

```
print(old_filepath)
```